# Lua send command line to Windows (& Mac)

Tags: cmd, terminal, lua, send, midi

I'm using [sendmidi](https://github.com/gbevin/SendMIDI/releases) to send midi to the Windows Midi Device or in Mac to the Mac Midi Device.
In Win I can send from the command prompt and same in the terminal:
`sendmidi.exe dev "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth" pc 17 channel 1 on 60 90`

Can I send command lines with Lua without executing a .bat or .vbs ?

I can get the script path where I have the Win & Mac executables sendmidi.exe & sendmidi with

```
local info = debug.getinfo(1,'S');
script_path = info.source:match[[^@?(.*[\/])[^\/]-$]]
```

I also need the CMD.exe window to run silent or minimized.

So I need to be able to send

```
"script_path..sendmidi.exe dev "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth" pc 17 channel 1 on 60 90"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local script_path = debug.getinfo(1, 'S').source:match[[^@?(.*[\/])[^\/]*$]] or ""
local command = '""'..script_path..'sendmidi.exe" dev "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth" pc 17 channel 1 on 60 90"'
os.execute(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.execute([command])
```

Please read the Lua manual...

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.execute